# Should host objects be counted as plain objects in an isPlainObject function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, lodash

I've been doing some testing of isPlainObject functions from different libraries on different browsers.

There are 4 different (code wise) isPlainObject functions being tested on a wide range of objects:

- jquery
- lodash
- utility (a library that I'm working on)
- alternative, suggested in comments below

All four of the above show differences on Chrome v23.0.1271.95 through to Chrome v25.0.1364.160, FireFox v 19.0 an Opera v12.14, but utility at least gives the same response of false for these object on all the browsers

[The tests on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ytkrV/10/) when run on Chrome

```
Failed to agree: JSON - jquery: true - utility: false - lodash: true - alt: false
Failed to agree: Math - jquery: true - utility: false - lodash: true - alt: false
Failed to agree: top - jquery: false - utility: false - lodash: true - alt: true
Failed to agree: parent - jquery: false - utility: false - lodash: true - alt: true
```

- true being that the routine thinks the object is plain, and false is not plain

**EDIT:** I believe that all routines are using the following similar *criteria*:

**jquery states**
***Check to see if an object is a plain object (created using "{}" or "new Object").***

**lodash states**
***Checks if a given value is an object created by the Object constructor.***

I understand that host objects are not the same as objects constructed by using "{}" or "new Object", so I guess my question is: should host objects be counted as plain objects?

Presently, utility is consistant and says they are not, the other routines give different results for host objects on different browsers.

**EDIT:** Accuracy of the result is the most important factor for me, performance is of secondary consideration.

Performance results of the 3 libraries and the suggested alternative are available on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-utility-isplainobject/11)

**EDIT:** this is the utility library function, so you don't need to search through the code.

```
defineProperty(utility, "isPlainObject", {
    value: (function () {
        var o = {};

        return function (obj) {
            try {
                return utility.isObject(obj) && getPrototypeOf(obj).isPrototypeOf(o);
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
        };
    }())
});
```

Comment: The jquery library documentation says up front that this may not work for object like the type you are testing: Note: Host objects (or objects used by browser host environments to complete the execution environment of ECMAScript) have a number of inconsistencies which are difficult to robustly feature detect cross-platform. As a result of this, $.isPlainObject() may evaluate inconsistently across browsers in certain instances.

Comment: So three different code libraries give 3 different results? Maybe it's because they're different libraries, and have different criteria.

Comment: ...put it this way, how do *you* want to define a plain object?

Comment: Check to see if an object is a plain object (created using "{}" or "new Object").

Comment: The criteria you listed isn't really criteria. Only be examining certain aspects of the object can you attempt to deduce if it's a "plain object". There's no built-in way right now. As such, each may have its own criteria for making this determination, and there's no absolutely perfect way.

Comment: ...Give this function a try: http://jsfiddle.net/g8sqj/ Though in browsers that don't support `Object.getPrototypeOf()`, you'll need to shim it. There's  no guaranteed shim for some browsers, so you may just need to provide an empty function, and rely on the testing in newer browsers.

Comment: I'm really only concerned about Chrome/Chromium for the code that I'm writing, but it never hurts to do a little testing on other browsers now and then. And as you can see I am already using `Object.getPrototypeOf` in my solution. I tested your method but as it stands it fails with "Uncaught TypeError: Object.getPrototypeOf called on non-object" in my tests. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytkrV/)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about primitives. Changing the first `if` statement would fix it. `if (o && typeof o === "object") {`

Comment: Changed on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytkrV/1/), it now exuecutes but gives a further difference on the same 4 suspect objects. At present it looks like $u gives the most reliable result. I'll wait for some answers to the question **And for each of the four objects, what should the correct result be** before drawing any conclusion though.

Comment: @Xotic750: Why does your code mess around with `constructor` properties?

Comment: @Bergi, I added the code to the question so that you can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All three of the above pass the tests when executed on FireFox v 19.0 an Opera v12.14

No, at least in Opera the tests in the fiddle fail for `window.screen`, `Math`, `JSON`, `DOMError`, `LSParserFilter`, `DOMImplementationLS`, `window.opera`, `SVGException`, and `document.implementation`.

> Is this a bug in Chrome/Chromium?

What? That different functions return different results? No.

> And for each of the four objects, what should the correct result be (so I can determine which function is the most accurate)?

How do you defined "correct"? How do you defined "plain object"?

> I believe that all 3 routines are using the following criteria:
>
> > *Check to see if an object is a plain object (created using "{}" or "new Object").*

That's hardly a useful criterion, since those objects where you experience discrepancies are not "created" - they are host objects (or even native objects) that just happen to exist.

Yet, we could compare which criteria those functions use:

- **jQuery** is very odd; you can read it's [source code at github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L424). In short: An object or function, whose [[Class]] is not one of `Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Error`, that has not a truthy `nodeName` property, that has not a `window` property pointing to itself, and that has no `constructor` property or whose `prototype` property of the `constructor` has an own `isPrototypeOf` property.

  They seem to do this for cross-browser support, but as you can see it fails in some cases where you would have it expected not to be a plain object.
- **Utility** is a bit obfuscated, but the check itself is simple: An object whose [[Class]] is `Object` and whose prototype is `Object.prototype` (or rather, whose prototype has a `isPrototypeOf` method that yields `true` for `{}`).
- **Lodash** has a few oddities like jQuery, but not that hard - you can read the [source at github](https://github.com/bestiejs/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L1851). It first checks for object type and not null, then gets `Object.prototype` via `getPrototypeOf(getPrototypeOf(…))` from a `valueOf` method if it exists. If it found one, either the object or its prototype must be that `Object.prototype` object and it must not be an `Arguments` object. If it did not found one, it falls back to the [shim](https://github.com/bestiejs/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L1006) which I'm not going to explain here.

  All these things are done to support detecting plain objects from different environments (e.g. iframes) with a different `Object.prototype` object and in browsers that do not provide a `getPrototypeOf` method.
- "**Alternative**" implementation: This tests the prototype of the object to be either `null` (but explicitly excluding `Object.prototype`) or to be `Object.prototype` and the [[Class]] value to be `Object`.

> should host objects be counted as plain objects?

Maybe. It always depends on your use case…

- act like it was created by `new Object`

  Then just `getPrototypeOf(obj) == Object.prototype` should be fine (if you don't need to support cross-frame objects). The `Math` and `JSON` objects would fulfill this requirement.
- Have no interfering enumerable properties on the prototypes

  Then you might also allow `getPrototypeOf(obj) == null` or even manually check for enumerable properties like lodash does. This would now include `Object.prototype` as a "plain object" for example.
- creatable by `new Object`

  Then also add the check for [[Class]] to be `Object` to exclude native objects like `JSON`, `Math`, `Arguments` and all those host objects with implementation-specific classes. Would you really expect those to be passed in the functions that test `isPlainObject`, and would they cause havoc if they passed the other tests?

See also [*Say what?* at niftysnippets.org](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html) (blog by T.J.Crowder)

Comment: I should really edit some of those comments, as my original fiddle had some issues which have been corrected. So yes, FireFox and Opera have even more differences, although the utility function appears to agree on all 3 browsers, and returns false for all the discrepancies. I don't know how to word the criteria better, I understand your and their documentation about host objects rather than constructed, but I think the essence should still be understood?

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to give thought and input on the question. Presently all 4 functions work just fine in the environment that I am writing code for, though this of course could change in the future. My current thinking is that host objects should not be classed as plain objects, which means that utility is correct for me, as it gives this answer across all the browsers and objects that I have tested so far. I'm not sure what complications this would hold if used in a cross-frame object scenario, my present understanding is not to that level.

Comment: The problem with iframes is that they have their own `window` instance with own global variables like `Array`. And that's a different `Array` than the parent window's `Array`, so an `instanceof` check for an array created with a literal in a script in the frame will fail against the parent `Array`.

Comment: Lo-Dash v1.1.0 will return `false` for built-ins with an internal [[Class]] other than "Object" too.