# How to judge whether a value is Object Literal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my limited experience about object type judgment,I don't know how to judge whether a value is Object Literal in JavaScript? I am searching for a long time on net.But no use.Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.Thanks in advance!

The solution is:
As we know,we can use 'typeof' or 'instanceof' to judge the type of value.
For example,to judge an Array,we can use:

```
var array=[0,1,2,3,4];
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(array)==='[object Array]'){
    alert('This is an Array!');
}
```

But now I want to check whether a value is Object Literal like this:

```
var obj={
    a:2
};
```

How to judge it?
My way is:

```
if(obj["__proto__"]["constructor"]===Object){
    alert("This is Object Literal");
}
```

I am afraid this way is wrong.

Comment: An object literal is a syntactical construct. It doesn't exist at runtime; at runtime, it's just an object, whether it was created as a literal or not.

Comment: In addition, you check for an array using `Array.isArray(arr)`

Comment: Have a look at [various ways to detect plain objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15315694/1048572). Basically just use `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) == Object.prototype`. Do not use the deprecated `__proto__` getter.

Comment: OK.Thank you!I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by matching the `constructor` property with `Object` like the following:

```js
var obj={
    a:2
};
console.log(obj.constructor == Object); // true

var arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr.constructor == Object); // false
```