# Javascript: How to differentiate object literals

Tags: javascript, json, object

I want to know how we can differentiate between object literals and json objects, with other objects such as Date, Function, etc.

Since the `typeof` operator as well as the `instanceof Object` operator returns true for both of the object, is there a way to differentiate between them?

PS: 
I don't want to do it by reverse exclusion of Date and Function, since it won't handle cases other than Date or function.

Comment: Have you tried `instanceof Date` for example, to check for Date object, rather then generic object?

Comment: Have a look at [various ways to detect plain objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15315694/1048572). Basically just use `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) == Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

Everything non-primitive is an object, but not everything that's an object is also a Date, or a function. Instead of checking `instanceof Object`, check `instanceof Date`, or `instanceof Function`:

```js
const obj = {};
const date = new Date();
const fn = () => 'foo';

console.log(date instanceof Date);
console.log(obj instanceof Date);

console.log(fn instanceof Function);
console.log(obj instanceof Function);
```

> and json objects

Keep in mind that [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: But what about other objects that are not Date or Function?

Comment: Just identify what you want to compare them against, then check their `instanceof`s, like I did above

Comment: My use case is this, I have a deep copy function that deep copies object but just returns everything as it is that is not a json.
In order to do that I have to be sure that the object I'm iterating is an actual object having keys
https://gist.github.com/Manzurkds/2bc6c11988aaabe8bd24d176eec2015f

Comment: Are you trying to differentiate between plain objects, and everything else which is not a plain object, is that it? (Anything that is in JSON format is a *string*, not an object, see link in answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a copy of a Javascript object (including arrays, since they're objects too), but excluding non-valid JSON objects (like `Date`s, `Function`s, etc.), one of the simplest way is to convert the Javascript object to JSON string, and then re-parse it:

```js
function deepCopy(input){
  const json = JSON.stringify(input);
  return JSON.parse(json);
}

const obj1 = { "hello": "world" };
const obj2 = deepCopy(obj1);

// obj1 and obj2 are two distinct objects
obj1["hello"] = "bye";
console.log( obj2["hello"] ); // world

// this works for arrays too
const a = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
const b = deepCopy(a);
```

> NOTE: be aware that, even if it works, it is not the best solution (especially because of performance issues).

You can also write a function, whose purpose is to analyze a Javascript object in order to see if it can be a valid JSON object (i.e. a plain Object with only primitives and arrays in it). This way, you can differentiate from `Date`s and other "complex" objects. Take a look at JSON specification (or Wikipedia) in order to know which data types JSON supports.