# create boolean for an object that is intended as a collection

Tags: javascript, object, collections, boolean

Given an input value, return true if the value is an Object intended as a
collection, false if otherwise.

In JavaScript, how can we decipher if a value is an Object, but not
null, not an Array, not a Date - all of these will return 'object' if used
with typeof.

```
function isObject(value) {
//code here//
}
```

Comment: You may find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/22482737/5865284

Comment: `let isObject = v => v && typeof v == "object" && !Array.isArray(v) && !(v instanceof Date);`

Comment: `value instanceof Map` will tell you if it is intended as a collection :-)

Comment: Have a look at [this exhaustive anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322968/1048572) covering possible ways to do what you want.