# Which function is better to cover most cases to check if a data is Object or not between 2 function below

Tags: javascript, object

I'm usually using this condition to check if a value of data is Object or not:

```
// function A
export const isObject = item => {
  return item && item.constructor === Object;
};
```

since it is easier to understand, but my friend usually using this function to check data with the same condition as above `isObject(value) {}`:

```
// function B
export function isObject(value) {
  return typeof value === "object" && !Array.isArray(value) && value !== null;
}
```

we got confused when there is a conflict when we want to merge to latest branch, so here is the question, `Between function A & B which one is better to cover most case regarding object data?`, Can you explain it too so I have a better knowledge about it.

Comment: I think I'd do `Object.getPrototypeOf(item) === Object.prototype`

Comment: @CertainPerformance thankyou for your response, so it means you chose a 3rd function possible for this case? can you explain it why you choose it?

Comment: There are objects for which your first function will return `false` but you second function will return `true`, and there are objects for which your first function will return `true`  but your second function will return `false`. They do very different things.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315694/should-host-objects-be-counted-as-plain-objects-in-an-isplainobject-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to identify plain objects that inherit from `Object.prototype`, and aren't subclasses of something else:

The first approach could be fooled because the `.constructor` property doesn't necessarily refer to the constructor function used to create the function - an object could assign something else to that property.

```js
const isObject = item => {
  return item && item.constructor === Object;
};
const a = [];
console.log(a.constructor == Array);
a.constructor = Object;
console.log(a.constructor === Object);
console.log(isObject(a));
```

The second approach could be fooled because there are other sorts of things than arrays that inherit from `Object.prototype` that aren't plain objects nor arrays - like HTMLElements and many, many other things.

```js
function isObject(value) {
  return typeof value === "object" && !Array.isArray(value) && value !== null;
}
console.log(isObject(document.body));
console.log(isObject(new Proxy({}, {})));
```

So I prefer `Object.getPrototypeOf`, with which you can be quite confident that the value's immediate internal prototype is `Object.prototype`, and that it's nothing else special.

```js
const isObject = item => Object.getPrototypeOf(item) === Object.prototype;
console.log(isObject([]));
console.log(isObject({}));
console.log(isObject(document));
```

It could fail if `Object.getPrototypeOf` is overwritten, of course - but if you're at that point, pretty much nothing is trustworthy anyway.

Note that many things inherit from `Object.prototype` which will give `true` for this, such as `Number.prototype` - if you want to exclude those kinds, you could check if a `.constructor` property exists.

Comment: thankyou for your answer, it really explain what kind of condition that the checker will failed regarding both of the function I mention above

Comment: oh can you edit it a little and put your function as the function you choose so it make anyone who see this problem easier to find the function for the answer