# Define JavaScript-Class Function outside of class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, lodash

I have a class called Conv. (Code at the end) It's for converting Objects via the run Function. In the "real" version there is also a runInverse() for simplicity reasons it's left out in this example.

i.e I can create a Conv and use it like this:

```js
function fn(s: String, inv: Boolean) {
  inv ? "inversed" : s
}

let conv = new Conv();
conv.fromPathToWithFn(data.id, fn, "internal_id");

conv.run({ data: { id: "1234" }}); // => { internal_id: "1234" }
```

The Converter is essentially a library and now I want to be able to define this fn as part of the conv but without modifying the Class on it's own.

That's so I'm able to access other values from the whole run / runInverse Object so that fn could look like this:

```js
function fn(s: String, inv: Boolean) {
  if (this.payload.otherValue) {
    return "nice"; 
  } else {
    return "s";
  }
}
```

And a request then would look like:

```js
conv.run({ data: { id: "1234" }, otherValue: "defined" }) // => { internal_id: "nice" });
```

Here the class

```js
export class Conv {
  converted: Array<any> = []; // The blueprint of conversions to be done
  inverse: Boolean = false; // Whether it's a normal or a inverse conversion (import/export)
  newPayload: object = {}; // the converted vehicle

  constructor() { }

  /**
   * Copies a value from one path into another
   *
   * @function fromPathTo
   * @memberof Conv
   *
   * @param {String} from Source-Path
   * @param {String} to Destination-Path
   * @return {void}
   */
  fromPathTo(from: String, to: String) {
    this.converted.push({ from, to });
  }

  /**
   * Takes the value in the Source-Path and uses it as an argument on the Converter-Function before putting it
   * into the Destination-Path
   *
   * @function fromPathToWithFn
   * @memberof Conv
   *
   * @param {String} from Source-Path
   * @param {Function} fn Converter-Function
   * @param {String} to Destination-Path
   */
  fromPathToWithFn(from: String, fn: Function, to: String) {
    this.converted.push({ from, fn, to });
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param {Object} payload The vehicle to be converted
   * @returns {Object} newPayload The converted vehicle
   */
  run(payload: Object, parentString: String = "") {
    this.inverse = false;

    /**
     * Without this if-Statement we can't use default values
     */
    if (typeof payload !== "object" || payload === null || Array.isArray(payload)) {
      return payload;
    }

    for (let prop in payload) {
      let currentPath: string = prop;
      if (parentString !== "") {
        currentPath = parentString + "." + prop;
      }
      if (
        typeof payload[prop] === "object" && !Array.isArray(payload[prop])
      ) {
        this.run(payload[prop], currentPath);
      } else {
        /**
         * @param {string} newProp Destination-Path
         */
        let newProp: string = this.converted.find(
          (_) => _.from === currentPath
        )?.to;
        /**
         * @param {Function|undefined} func Converter-Function
        */
        let func: Function | undefined = this.converted.find(
          (_) => _.from === currentPath
        )?.fn;
        /**
         * @param {string|null} def Default-Value
        */
        let def: String | null = this.converted.find(
          (_) => _.from === currentPath
        )?.def;

        // Check wether Value should even be used in this conversion
        if (newProp === undefined || newProp === null) {
          break;
        }

        if (newProp && newProp !== prop) {
          // Only call the function if it's not undefined
          // and set the Destination-Path to the default value if the Source-Value is null
          typeof func !== "undefined"
            ? lodash.set(
              this.newPayload,
              newProp,
              func(this.run(lodash.get(payload, prop)), this.inverse)
            )
            : this.run(lodash.get(payload, prop)) === null ||
              typeof this.run(lodash.get(payload, prop)) === "undefined"
              ? lodash.set(this.newPayload, newProp, def)
              : lodash.set(
                this.newPayload,
                newProp,
                this.run(lodash.get(payload, prop))
              );
        } else {
          // Only call the function if it's not undefined
          // and set the Destination-Path to the default value if the Source-Value is null
          typeof func !== "undefined"
            ? lodash.set(
              this.newPayload,
              prop,
              func(this.run(lodash.get(payload, prop)), this.inverse)
            )
            : this.run(lodash.get(this.newPayload, currentPath)) === null ||
              typeof this.run(lodash.get(this.newPayload, prop)) === "undefined"
              ? lodash.set(this.newPayload, currentPath, def)
              : lodash.set(
                this.newPayload,
                currentPath,
                this.run(lodash.get(payload, prop))
              );
        }
      }
    }
    return this.newPayload;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can paste into our own IDEs and get to work on it.  A verbal description of a class isn't something an IDE can use, so we either have to give answers without testing it first, or make guesses about what your class looks like, and it's easy to guess incorrectly.

Comment: I added the class code to my original question

Comment: By the by, there is no JSON involved here. Those are just objects, not "JSON-Objects". Using terms like "JSON-Objects" dilutes the meaning of JSON, which is simply a format for exchanging data.

Comment: Please review the guidelines for what constitutes a [mre]; it's not just pasting code from your code base, unfortunately.  It should be both *minimal*, meaning that anything not directly needed for your question should be removed or replaced with a toy/simpler version, and *reproducible*, meaning that anything needed for others to see your issue should be present.  Right now that code is pretty big so it's unlikely to be minimal, and it apparently depends on lodash so it's not reproducible (unless you think your *question* depends on lodash, in which case it should be tagged as such).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I get why people get all up in arms about the "JSON object" thing, but we need a way to talk about plain data objects (as opposed to ones with methods, getters, setters, visibility modifiers, etc). If we don't provide an alternative people are going to keep using it. POJO?

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm not sure why "object" doesn't work. If you want to talk about objects with adornments, talk about the adornments. Seems like we made it this far without needing a special word for objects. If we must, POJO works, although I don't know if Java people might have a problem talking about POJO-to-POJO transformation :).

Comment: @jcalz I tried simplifying it even more. Yes it depends on lodash. But that's ok imo. Additionally I added the lodash flag to the Question now.

Comment: It's okay if you want to make the question depend on lodash, but it means those of us who don't have expertise in lodash will probably not engage further.  Good luck!

Comment: @JaredSmith "*plain object*" (the very term you used) works fine (although [there is no precise definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322968/1048572)). Same for POJO though, which commonly have getters and accessors.